# project having web api not working on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have deployed project on IIS 8.5. Project has webApi restful services which are being called from jquery ajax.

Now the solution is working perfectly on IIS express .. i.e. its returning expected Json but when deployed on IIS with virtual directory , it stopped working. The problem was narrowed down to webApi.
I tried several options.. changing webApi route .. checking verbs .. enabling MARS.. but still its returning error 500.

Any ideas or direction to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried [remote debugging](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40781)?

Comment: well not exactly.. but i monitored network requests.. rest of the resources.. i.e. images,html,css etc are loading ..

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be causing a 500 error on this. In my past experience with deploying Wep Api or MVC projects to production servers, the following issues could be causing an internal server error:

- The virtual directory was not setup as an application in IIS.
- The IIS application pool that you assigned to the application is not using the same version of the .NET framework that you compiled it in.
- Your application is sharing an application pool with other apps that are compiled with a different version of the .NET framework (e.g. 2.0 and 4.5). All apps on an App Pool should be using the same version of .NET.
- When you deployed the application to the server, some of the files did not get copied over to the root directory somehow. Make sure your server directory has a bin folder and a global.asax file in it.

Hopefully your issue is something simple. If it was working on IIS Express just fine, I suspect that one of these items is the problem.

Comment: Did any of this help you?